# Django XMPP Connection pooling

Tags: python, django, xmpp, connection-pooling

How can i pool a connection to XMPP server in django so that it is available across multiple requests. I don't want to connect and authenticate on every request which makes it a bit slow. Is this possible?

EDIT:

I am using xmpppy python xmpp library

Comment: Please provide more info on the method you are using to connect to XMPP-server as the answer depends on this, e.g. there are a bit different ways to solve your problem if you are using pyxmpp or not.

Comment: I am using xmpppy - python xmpp lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `xmpppy` has its own main loop I suggest to use it in a separate thread or even start separately. Actually you do have two separate applications: website and xmpp-client and it is normal to run them separately.

In this case you may use different ways to communicate between your applications: pipes between threads and/or processes, tcp or unix socket, file queue, different amqp silutions, any persistent storage, even d-bus, etc. But that is a subject for another question I think.